# Can QGIS be used to mass convert CRS coordinates in a data table?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector

I collected Geophysics data on three separate occasions. Each data-point is geo-referenced. In one instance I mistakenly collected data in a different CRS than the others so one set of data is in British National Grid while the other two are WGS 84. I was able to successfully merge the vector data for display but I'd like to export the points to a data table with them all in the same CRS. Can this be done?

For reference I'm running QGIS 3.22.1-Białowieża

Comment: Export -> Save features as -> Format CSV?

Answer (score 1):

To get the correct WGS84 coordinates when exporting to a CSV even for the points that have coordinate values stored in British National Grid, first create a new attribute field (or update an existing coordinate field) with [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator).

1. Use Field calculator with the expression `x (transform ($geometry, 'EPSG:27700','EPSG:4326'))` for longitude and replace `x` by `y` for latitude. 27700 is the EPSG code for the initial CRS (British National Grid).
2. Then right click layer > export > Save features as... > select Format `Comma Separated Values (CSV)`

Answer (score 0):

You can export your table with the new CRS and then merge it with the others.